# Boto3 --> Modifying EC2's instance to have multiple Security Groups

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a couple of Security Groups I'd like to attach to an EC2 instance.
I tried the following but failed:

```
sg_1 = 'sg-something'
sg_2 = 'sg-else'
response = instance.modify_attribute(Groups=sg_1, sg_2)
```

And something like this:

```
response = instance.modify_attribute(Groups=[sg_1, sg_2])
```

And something like this:

```
for sg in sg_1, sg_2:
    response = instance.modify_attribute(Groups=[sg_1, sg_2])
```

It seems like it can only accept one sg at a time but when I pass the second one it overwrites the previous one.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: There is a discrepancy of your api compare to boto3 documentation, I only see service resource modify_attribute only used to modify AMI attribute, not  instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked fine for me:

```
import boto3

client=boto3('ec2')

response = client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId='i-1234',Groups=['sg-1111','sg-2222'])
```

Or using the resource version:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instance = ec2.Instance('i-1234')
instance.modify_attribute(Groups=['sg-1111','sg-2222'])
```