# Boto3 How to add a security group to an ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-security-group

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

instance = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-0fc970315c2d38f01',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.nano')
print(instance[0].id)

instance = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='MyWebServer', Description = 'WebServer', VpcId='vpc-0dea879f34afff60d')
```

This is what I have so far, it creates the instance and the security group for me but doesn't add both together. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166293/boto3-modifying-ec2s-instance-to-have-multiple-security-groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just overwrites the `instance` variable with the security group:

```
instance = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='MyWebServer', Description = 'WebServer', VpcId='vpc-0dea879f34afff60d')
```

There's nothing in your code that is making any attempt to assign the security group to the EC2 instances. The easiest way is to create the security group first, and then include it in the `create_instances` call, like this:

```
sg = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='MyWebServer', Description = 'WebServer', VpcId='vpc-0dea879f34afff60d')

instance = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-0fc970315c2d38f01',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.nano',
 SecurityGroups=[ sg.group_id ] 
)
```

Comment: Oh so I basically just made it more complicated for myself... Makes sense looking at the code but when I run it I receive an error saying ''(InvalidParameterValue) when  calling the RunInstances  operation: Value () parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty."

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It creates the security group but doesn't create the instance when called

Comment: Try printing `sg.group_id` to make sure it isn't empty.

Comment: It gives me an error trying to print it after I create the security group.
"print[sg.group_id]  TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Try `SecurityGroupIds` instead of `SecurityGroups`. I'm not sure why there are two versions of that property on the EC2 resource, and they both take lists of strings...

Comment: `print[]` is invalid Python syntax as the error clearly states, it would be `print(sg.group_id)`

Comment: Oh my bad, yeah it displays the security group ID when I print it and when inputting SecurityGroupsIds it gives a different error of "Unknown parameter in input: "SecurityGroupsIds", must be one of : BlockDeviceMapping, ImageId, InstanceType, Ipv6AddressCount... etc"

Comment: even now i'm just getting an error of " (InvalidParameter) when calling the RunInstances operationn: Security group sg-0f6364ba81996a69 and subnet subnet-83cfabe5 belong to different networks."

Comment: OK you have it almost correct now. You need to add a subnetID to the EC2 instance, because it is currently creating it in the default VPC instead of VPC with the ID `vpc-0dea879f34afff60d` that you created the security group in.

Comment: What Subnet ID would I be inputting and would I create a NetworkInterface field within the create EC2 instance method to call the subnetId? If so I just need to know what I would be inputting as the Subnet ID so they belong to the same network.

Comment: You need to go look at your VPC to determine the subnet ID, I can't tell you what the ID should be. You don't need to specify `NetworkInterface` you just need to specify `SubnetId="#####"`. Please have a look at the documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances

Comment: Oh I thought it was a specific Subnet ID I needed to issue as when I go to subnets I have like 9 of the same under the same VPC, I inputted one of them and it seems to work smoothly now which is great thanks to you. If I was to go abouts accessing it via SSH into port 80 and port 22 would it be much extra code needed to do so?

Comment: SSH would be port `22`. Port 80 would be HTTP, not SSH. Are you asking how to access the server over those ports via Python? Did you assign a public IP to the server so it would be accessible? What is your end goal?

Comment: Yeah I meant to say how would I make an instance accessible using my SSH key? and each instance has a public IP address related to it if that's what u meant.

Comment: You needed to setup the SSH key ahead of time in AWS, and then specify the SSH key ID as one of the parameters in the `create_instances` call.

Comment: Would that be my API credentials or is there an actual way of setting up the SSH key within amazon.

Comment: An SSH key is not the same as your AWS API credentials. Please see the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#prepare-key-pair

Comment: Ohh SSH is the key, sorry for the dumb questions i'm a bit rusty on AWS terms, should of researched before I asked but I understand, thanks for all your help. Will let you know if I get stuck on anything else.